Validate XML agains .XSD schema using cxml-rng
I'am trying to verify a bunch of XML files against a set schema stored in .XSD format. As I understand, cxml-rng has support for .xsd, but I cant make it work.
Here is the function performing the validation:
(defun validate (xml xsd)
  (let* ((schema    (cxml-rng:parse-schema xsd))
         (validator (cxml-rng:make-validator schema)))
    (cxml:parse-file xml validator))

However, running this yields the following error:
Error: Call to  (SETF CXML-RNG::GRAMMAR-START) which was not defined at compile time with arguments (#S(CXML-RNG::DEFINITION :NAME :START :COMBINE-METHOD NIL :HEAD-P NIL :REDEFINITION NIL :CHILD #) #S(CXML-RNG::GRAMMAR :START NIL :PARENT NIL :DEFINITIONS #))>

I was using xmllint for the same job, which indicates that the schema file is valid.
Any suggestions?

May we have XML and XSD snippets to play around?

btw I can see some updates in this fork (forked in 2011): https://github.com/mcna/cxml-rng … only misses the last commit afaik.

@Ehvince: Unfortunatelly the XMLs contain sensitive stuff, so I cannot share any of it.
We've been using XML Notepad and command line programs to validate them, but some users are not comfortable with such tools, so I am looking at options to automate some of it.

If you could provide a couple very simple files that reproduce your file structures, with only dumb and anonymized content, it will easier for us to reproduce the issue and give it a look.

A sample XML and schema is available here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cbWM-mWtV6Bu0EZQ3JRV3bXbLfxbyXcP?usp=drive_link
